# How to integrate moengage in ReactJs app?

Tags: reactjs, moengage

Has any one of you successfully integrate [Moengage](https://docs.moengage.com/docs/web-sdk-integration) in ReactJs ? I have try it by put this inside `<head>` tag on index.html of HTMLWebpackPlugin's template.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m,n){
        i['moengage_object']=r;t={}; q = function(f){return function(){(i['moengage_q']=i['moengage_q']||[]).push({f:f,a:arguments});};};
        f = ['track_event','add_user_attribute','add_first_name','add_last_name','add_email','add_mobile',
        'add_user_name','add_gender','add_birthday','destroy_session','add_unique_user_id','moe_events','call_web_push','track','location_type_attribute'];
        for(k in f){t[f[k]]=q(f[k]);}
        a=s.createElement(o);m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
        i['moe']=i['moe'] || function(){n=arguments[0];return t;}; a.onload=function(){if(n){i[r] = moe(n);}};
    })(window,document,'script','https://cdn.moengage.com/webpush/moe_webSdk.min.latest.js','Moengage'); 
</script>
```

I put the moengage's config in a file called 'moengage.js'. So i can easily import & use it in another files.

```js
export const Moengage = moe({
    app_id:"APP ID",
    debug_logs: 0
});
```

Then, i use it in another file

```js
import { Moengage } from '../config/moengage.js'

...
Moengage.track_event('Loan_Data', {
      'loan_name': 'Example name',
      'loan_type_id': 123,
})
```

Unfortunately, mine doesn't work. Did you ever try moengage on ReactJs ? Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: It looks like you've tried a good approach; what exactly is going wrong? Are there errors, does nothing happen, have you checked the script is correctly imported (for instance no errors about undefined Moengage etc)?

Comment: @ChrisCousins .. Nothing errors appear in the console of Chrome Dev Tools. But, my friend of mine said that on MoEngage's Dashboard, there is no log of event that has been fired from moengage tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `moe` is available in the window and thus putting it in a config file will not work. The initialization script has to be placed in the `<head>` tag.

You can access the `moe` variable through the `window` wherever required. In your config file you can try something like this:

`export const Moengage = window.moe({
    app_id:"APP ID",
    debug_logs: 0
});`

PS. I develop the Web SDK at MoEngage. Please feel free to reach out to us at support@moengage.com for any further queries.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your reply. I will try it later and let you know if it have success

Comment: i try to use moengage with Nuxt. I follow the webSDK example here https://github.com/moengage/webSDK-sample/blob/master/nuxt-spa/plugins/moe.js#L54

But if i use `inject('moengage', Moengage)` in Nuxt, it wont work. It only work if we call via `window.Moengage`, why?